# How do you make a StopWatch in android using the chronometer?

Tags: java, android, stopwatch

I'm trying to make a stopwatch for android as part of a score board app the problem is I'm not sure how to use the `chronometer to start, stop, then resume` from the time it stopped at or reset to 0. The only problem is that I'm not sure how to use the `setBase()` and `getBase()` methods properly.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int homecount, awaycount, minutes, seconds;
    TextView home, away;
    Button stop, start, reset, addhome, subhome, addaway, subaway;
    TextView time;
    public boolean running;


    Chronometer MyChronometer;
    long startTime, stopTime;
    running = false;
    stopTime = 0;
    MyChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timer);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timer)).start();
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            running = true;
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timer)).stop();
            stopTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            running = false;
        }
    });

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: All your assignments should be within a method in your class, like `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variable `MyChronometer`. Use that every time you want to start or stop.

Also, right after initialization you should run `MyChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());`. For more details read the documentation: [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#setBase%28long%29) and [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29).